# NetLogo nw extension: how to save the links reported by `nw:weighted-path-to`?

Tags: netlogo

I want to save the links of the shortest path between the source and destination , so thagt i can change their color to red ie the links' color. But theres is no primitive to save the links 
the code is:

```
          ask nodes with [label = "Source" ]
         [
           show  nw:weighted-path-to  turtle nodenumberdestination "bandwidth"
         ]
```

can somebody tell me how to save the links reported by the nw primitive used above, so as to change their color to red in the graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by saving the links, but you can store the list of links in a variable. So, if you have a turtles-own variable `path-to-destination`, you can just do

```
ask nodes with [label = "Source" ] [
  set path-to-destination nw:weighted-path-to turtle nodenumberdestination "bandwidth"
]
```

Alternatively, you can just store the list of links in a local variable if you don't need to do anything with them later:

```
ask nodes with [label = "Source" ] [
  let path-to-destination nw:weighted-path-to turtle nodenumberdestination "bandwidth"
]
```

As for turning them red, `nw:weighted-path-to` returns a list of links, so we can just loop through that list ask each to become red. Extending the previous code, that looks like:

```
ask nodes with [label = "Source" ] [
  let path-to-destination nw:weighted-path-to turtle nodenumberdestination "bandwidth"
  foreach path-to-destination [ ask ? [ set color red ] ]
]
```

Comment: Thankyou so much sir... yes i actually wanted to turn the color of links on the way to shortest path to red. Your answer really solved my problem. I m really thankfull to you.

Comment: Sir can we contact you in case we need some help?
We are a group of students from india currently working on netlogo as a part of our project.We would be very glad if you could provide us your facebook profile link , to contact you further.
Thank you

Comment: Glad that worked for you! I prefer to answer questions on here. NetLogo questions usually get answered pretty quick here, so this is a good place to go for help. I'm pretty active here, so I'll definitely see any questions you post. Also, don't forget to mark an answer as correct if it fixed your problem! That's the little check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Sir, we wanted to implement Djikstras's algo aswell in netLogo, but we are finding difficulties in codin .

Comment: The nw extension uses Dijkstra's algorithm for weighted path calculation. If you need to implement it yourself for some reason, try out some things. If you run into specific problems, open up new questions in stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.. You saved our day. We are really in your debt.:-)

Comment: Sir , is there any primitive to introduce a delay in the running of the netlogo inbetween the execution of a model?

Comment: Would you mind opening a new question to ask that? That way, other users can easily find the answer. Thanks!